# how to save inkcanvas strokes in pdf

Tags: c#, xaml, pdf, win-universal-app, inkcanvas

I would like to create an application (uwp) for annotating PDF.
I Use InkCanvas to write with the pen, my problem is to save the strokes in the pdf file.
I've read several responses on this topic, and all indicate to save strokes in .isf file, thus separating the pdf with strokes.
I would use a solution such as drawboard application, that is, save the pdf including stroke, then you can edit the pdf and previous strokes.
it can do that? how can I save the strokes within the pdf document?
thank you

Comment: do you mean to embed the strokes into PDF (and thus modifying the PDF file)? try [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Comment: yes Save the stroke into pdf and with the possibility of reopening the pdf and edit strokes.i will try itextsharp